# Cannot find 'IsacCodec' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, video

getting an error ,
Cannot find 'IsacCodec' in scope in swift ios ,
even after updating pods with
'TwilioVideo (5.8.0)' version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mm25.png)

refer above screenshot for more.

Let me get the solution on this as soon as possible.

Comment: "... as soon as possible", https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest